# add-member for formatted addition to Write-Output

Tags: powershell

Currently, printing a `Get-Process` object yields

```
PS > $p = Get-Process procexp
PS > $p
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
    293      10    10660       8060   122   163.19    196 procexp
```

I want to print a clean table that includes a `Datetime` value.
There are many ways to do this.  I'm trying to do this by adding a property to `$p`.  I *want* it too look like (notice the new column on the right side):

```
PS > $p = Get-Process procexp
PS > $d = Get-Date
PS > $p | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DateTime -Value $d.DateTime
PS > $p
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName Datetime
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- ----------- --------
    293      10    10660       8060   122   163.19    196 procexp     Friday February 20, 2015 00:20:00
```

Unfortunately, the column `DateTime` does not print.  Calling `Add-Member` has no affect on what `$p` prints to stdout.

Does anyone know how to add an object member such that it automatically prints in a table like this?

Comment: By automatically, do you mean just how to get the property to display in a table?  Or do you mean how to get it to display when you pass `$p` with no parameters to Write-Output?  The former you can get by using Format-Table with the -Property parameter.

Comment: @RyanBemrose I mean both (it's been a long time since I powershelled)?  I guess by your questions that "_property to display in a table_" and "_display with no parameters to Write-Output_" are very different things.
Let's focus on "_get member to display when you pass $p with no parameters to Write-Output_" .

Comment: The difference is what end product you're going for.  If you just want the table with the extra column, then `$p | Format-Table -Property myProperty,Handles,NPM,etc` will get you what you want.  If instead you want an object which will generate your desired table when fed to Powershell's default display routine, then I guess you have to modify the data type of that object.  I'm not sure how to do that, but I might start with `help about_Types.ps1xml`

Answer (score 0):

$p | select name,Handles,NPM,@{Label='Date'; Expression={Get-date} } 
you can add | ft -AutoSize at the end to have good looking table and aobiously you'll have to add all properties you want to display.

See how values from get-process being formated, all information about formatiing data based on data types can be found in: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\DotNetTypes.format.ps1xml

you can play around hashtables in Select or Format-XXX  comandlets, in this particular case I've added current date to be displayed for each line in PS Example: @{Label='VM'; Expression={$_.VM / 1Mb}} this expression in Select will display VM in MegaBytes.

Cheers
/Anton